# Return List<User> using Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm developing a WCF Rest service that connect to a database using Entity Framework 4.4.

I have this method:

```
public List<User> GetAllUsers()
{
    using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
    {
        var users = from u in context.Users
                    select u;

    }
}
```

And I don't know how to return a `List<User>` with all `User`s retrieved from database.

**Do I have to do this?**

```
public List<User> GetAllUsers()
{
    List<User> usersList = null;

    using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
    {
        var users = from u in context.Users
                    select u;

        usersList = new List<User>();
        foreach (User user in users)
            usersList.Add(user);
    }

    return usersList;
}
```

Or, **is there a fastest way to do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, like this:

```
return context.Users.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var users = from u in context.Users
                    select u;
return users.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
public List<User> GetAllUsers()
{

    using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
    {
        var users = from u in context.Users
                    select u;

        return users.ToList();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<User> GetAllUsers()
{
    using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
    {
        var users = (from u in context.Users
                    select u).Tolist();


        return users 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
{    
  return context.Users.Select(u=>u).ToList();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is ok

```
public List<User> GetAllUsers()
{
    using(var context = new AdnLineContext())
    {
     var users = (from u in context.Users
                  select u).ToList();
     return users;
    }
}
```